# codeigniter active record, generate, but do not execute query

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord

I am working a library that needs to be fed sql queries as strings todo its job.

I am using CodeIgniter and the active record implementation of their database class.

I know that I can echo the SQL statement like so... But I only want to generate this query, not execute it.

```
 echo $this->db->last_query();
```

Any help accomplishing this would be great!

Comment: what about echo "{$this->db->last_query()}";   ?

Comment: I'm trying to get the SQL statement without executing the querie...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last_query() function you are using returns the query string, it doesn't execute the it.  Try assigning the function return to a variable for use in your library.

```
$str = $this->db->last_query();
```

Comment: this will execute query first then get the string sql, user get_compiled_select/update/insert instead ...

Comment: this is returner after query execution ... so the answer is not right

Answer (score 6):

with a little hack you can do it go to system/DB_active_rec.php and remove protected keyword form _compile_select method and now

```
return $this->db->_compile_select();
```

Also use `$this->db->from('table');`

Instead of `get()` because get will execute query
Here is an example

```
function index(){
    $this->db->select('blah blah');
    $this->db->from('table');
    $string = $this->db->_compile_select();
    return $string;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Depends which type of query it is. insert and update have methods to allow you to do this.

```
$this->db->set('foo', $bar);
$this->db->update_string('table'); // UPDATE table SET foo = "bar"
```

Comment: I am looking to generate select queries only.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer!! Well done, never knew about this!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is a safe practice but the db object stores its queries in the queries attribute so you can get it via:

```
$this->db->queries
```

which returns an array of queries.

Comment: Properties should not be accessed like this as that is exactly the sort of thing likely to get turned into a private property when we get around to PHP5ifying the scopes. But yes, it will probably work.

Comment: @Phil, is there a way for me to get the sql statement without executing the query?

Comment: Answered instead of commented, oops.

Answer (score 0):

As of Codeigniter 3 you can use [`get_compiled_select()`](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#selecting-data)

To use it before CI3, see [Is there a function like _compile_select or get_compiled_select()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9232316/is-there-a-function-like-compile-select-or-get-compiled-select)