# Is there a function like _compile_select or get_compiled_select()?

Tags: codeigniter, activerecord, codeigniter-2

Looks like `_compile_select` is deprecated and `get_compiled_select` is not added to 2.1.0. Are there any other functions like those two? And also I am curious. Is there any particular reason to not adding `get_compiled_select()` to Active Record and removing `_compile_select`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I've added get_compiled_select() to DB_active_rec.php and it seems to work without problem, but i wouldn't remove _compile_select() since it's used in many other methods.

The pull request for adding this method is here, with some other useful methods like:

- get_compiled_select()
- get_compiled_insert()
- get_compiled_update()
- get_compiled_delete()

https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/pull/307

if you want just the method, it's just this:

```
/**
 * Get SELECT query string
 *
 * Compiles a SELECT query string and returns the sql.
 *
 * @access  public
 * @param   string  the table name to select from (optional)
 * @param   boolean TRUE: resets AR values; FALSE: leave AR vaules alone
 * @return  string
 */
public function get_compiled_select($table = '', $reset = TRUE)
{
    if ($table != '')
    {
        $this->_track_aliases($table);
        $this->from($table);
    }

    $select =  $this->_compile_select();

    if ($reset === TRUE)
    {
        $this->_reset_select();
    }

    return $select;
}
```