# php Codeigniter - error while executing library Subquery.php

Tags: php, codeigniter, subquery

I have been using a library for subqueries to work - Subquery.php
Ref : https://github.com/NTICompass/CodeIgniter-Subqueries

```
$this->db->select('test');
$this->db->select('test2');
$this->db->from('table');
$sub = $this->subquery->start_subquery('where_in');
$sub->select('IDs');
$sub->from('idTable');
$sub->where('date', '2011-07-10');
$this->subquery->end_subquery('id');
```

I think that this statement:

```
$sub = $this->subquery->start_subquery('where_in');
```

contains the error. When I execute this line, I get a blank page.
The fn. start_subquery is:

```
function start_subquery($statement, $join_type = '', $join_on = 1){
        $db = $this->CI->load->database('', true); // after executing this statement, a blank page shows...
        $this->dbStack[] = $db;
        $this->statement[] = $statement;
        if(strtolower($statement) == 'join'){
            $this->join_type[] = $join_type;
            $this->join_on[] = $join_on;
        }
        return $db;
    }
```

FYI - In my database.php:

```
$active_group = 'default'
$active_record = TRUE;
```

And CI version is 2.1.0

Comment: Try in your controller: `$this->load->database('',true);` and check it!

Comment: Thanks for the reply but... No, its not working. :(. If that is the case, what should be replaced with the statement : $db = $this->CI->load->database('', true); in start_subquery function ?

Comment: The `load->database()` should work. So please don't change! I think this subquery-library is ok. IMHO the problem is your database configuration in CI: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/configuration.html

Please check!

Comment: I have already checked the db config file and the doc.  <br/>

$active_group = 'default';  <br/>
$active_record = TRUE;<br/><br/>

$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';<br/>
$db['default']['username'] = '****';<br/>
$db['default']['password'] = '***';<br/>
$db['default']['database'] = '****';<br/>
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';<br/><br/>

The rest of the config is default.

Comment: Can you use any function of db? E.g. a simple `select` as can see http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/examples.html ?

Comment: Yes, of-course. I have been using $this->db->select, for E.g., in many of the model functions and those queries work perfect.

Comment: It's strange. You call `load->database('',true)` and your queries doesn't work anymore?

Comment: I haven't called `load->database('',true)` in any of the controller functions for queries to execute. And yesterday, I have found a solution, and I don't know if it is the right way. Please correct me if I am wrong. As suggested in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9232316/is-there-a-function-like-compile-select-or-get-compiled-select), I have added the function `get_compiled_select()` system > database > DB_active_rec.php, and the queries are working fine now. But I remember the guidelines of CI, that, the system folder should not be edited. Do you have a better solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm, understand. As I see the subquery's source code in line 27, it wants to call `_compile_select` or `get_compiled_select`. If you can check in CI's `DB_active_rec.php` the `_compile_select` is protected so you can't access from Subquery (it isn't subclass of `db`).

Possible solution: `_compile_select()` should public or class `Subquery` should be extend of CI's db class. I think you should report this to author of Subquery.

Or you can extend the CI's db class :)

Sorry - I want to write it as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, I have changed the stmt. `class Subquery` to `class Subquery extends CI_DB_active_record` in Subquery.php and it is working fine. And yes, I will report this to the author. :)

Comment: `extends CI_DB_active_record` actually works?  I thought CodeIgniter was removing the ability to extend DB classes.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote that library, so thanks for using it.  The problem is (as [@uzsolt has stated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10793787/206403)) is that `_compile_select` is protected.  It used to not be in CodeIgniter 1.7.x (it was just a neat hidden method some devs found).

In the dev version of CodeIgniter on GitHub (https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter), there is a public `get_compiled_select` method.  Seems this change hasn't been pushed to the stable build yet.

So, to get this library to work, you can try using the development version of CodeIgniter.  I'm pretty sure they are going to remove the ability to `extend CI_DB_active_record` in the future (http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html).