# Codeigniter: does $this->db->last_query(); execute a query?

Tags: codeigniter, activerecord, codeigniter-2

Does query execution happen at the `get_where()` clause of the following codeigniter active record statement?

```
$this->db->select('*');
    $q = $this->db->get_where('Contacts', array('id' => $contact_id));

    $sql = $this->db->last_query();
```

Or does it happens once you call the `result_array()`?

And is `$this->db->last_query();` a reliable way in getting the query string.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

The query execution happens on all get methods like

```
$this->db->get('table_name');
$this->db->get_where('table_name',$array);
```

While last_query contains the last query which was run

```
$this->db->last_query();
```

If you want to get query string without execution you will have to do this.
Go to system/database/DB_active_rec.php Remove public or protected keyword from these functions

```
public function _compile_select($select_override = FALSE)
public function _reset_select()
```

Now you can write query and get it in a variable

```
$this->db->select('trans_id');
$this->db->from('myTable');
$this->db->where('code','B');
$subQuery = $this->db->_compile_select();
```

Now reset query so if you want to write another query the object will be cleared.

```
$this->db->_reset_select();
```

And the thing is done. Cheers!!!
Note : While using this way you must use

```
$this->db->from('myTable')
```

instead of

```
$this->db->get('myTable')
```

which runs the query.

[Take a look at this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11023318/using-mysql-where-in-clause-in-codeigniter/11031431#11031431)

Comment: Welcome and No problemo! They are going to add these two methods(and some other for insert , update and delete etc) in the new version of CI so we will not have to hack it.

Comment: @raheelshan this just saved my life. do you have any info about why they made this functions protected ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9232316/is-there-a-function-like-compile-select-or-get-compiled-select

Comment: Please don't call any method with `_` which means private access (not from outside). That is no solution but a problem with later updates (when they added real access levels to their methods).

Comment: i don't think that method start with _ will create any problem.

Answer (score 4):

For me `save_queries` option was turned off so,

```
$this->db->save_queries = TRUE; //Turn ON save_queries for temporary use.
$str = $this->db->last_query();
echo $str;
```

Ref: [Can't get result from $this->db->last_query(); codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45363375/cant-get-result-from-this-db-last-query-codeigniter)

Answer (score 0):

For Me It Works Perfectly: [Source](https://tutorialz.tech/get-last-query-in-codeigniter/) Disclosure : This Source website Belongs to me , i am also sharing solutions on my website ...

```
public function index()
{
    $db = \Config\Database::connect();
    $heroesCount = $db->table('products')->countAll();
    echo $db->getLastQuery();
    exit;
}
```