# How to echo/print query in bonfire..?

Tags: php, codeigniter, bonfire

If I want to echo my current query in bonfire which function provide functionality like laravel provide to_sql()

Comment: Not having seen any of your code, will `_compile_select()` work?

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15953811/codeigniter-this-db-last-query-executes-query and `echo $this->db->last_query();`

Comment: @wolfgang1983 : last_query is for codeigniter so it'll working in bonfire also..?

Comment: Its codeigniter based so would think so