# codeigniter query prbolem

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

This code is working perfectaly in mysql run command

```
SELECT employeeCode
FROM employee_details
WHERE employeeCode
IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT (employeeCode) FROM quiz_answer_detailsWHERE submitTime
    IN (SELECT MIN( submitTime ) FROM quiz_answer_details WHERE quizId
    IN (SELECT id FROM quiz_details WHERE uploadtime =  '2014-04-03')
    AND answer IN (SELECT answer FROM quiz_details WHERE uploadtime =  '2014-04-03'))
   )
```

But I want to use this code on my codeigniter, but it is not working.
My codeigniter query code is

```
    $this->db->select('employeeCode');
    $this->db->from('employee_details');
    $this->db->where_in('employeeCode');
    $this->db->select('DISTINCT(employeeCode)');
    $this->db->from('quiz_answer_details');
    $this->db->where_in('submitTime');
    $this->db->select('min(submitTime)');
    $this->db->from('quiz_answer_details');
    $this->db->where_in('quizId');
    $this->db->select('id');
    $this->db->from('quiz_details');
    $this->db->where('uploadtime',"2014-04-03");
    $this->db->where_in('answer');
    $this->db->select('answer');
    $this->db->from('quiz_details');
    $this->db->where('uploadtime',"2014-04-03");
    $query=$this->db->get();
    print_r($query);
    if($query->num_rows>=1)
    {
        return $query;
    }
    else
    {
         return false;
    }
```

What is wrong please help me

Comment: What is the version of CodeIgniter you use?

Comment: I've seen a lot, but Active Records used like this... never.

Comment: If CodeIgniter 3 - use `get_compiled_select()`, if CodeIgniter 2 - see [Is there a function like _compile_select or get_compiled_select()?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9232316/1356425) and related questions about generating queries with subqueries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should re write you subquery and use joins instead to get the better performance,without having full information regarding your tables/relationship and desired result i can't provide you the new query but you can use your subquery in active record's where function

```
$subquery=" SELECT DISTINCT (employeeCode) FROM quiz_answer_detailsWHERE submitTime
    IN (SELECT MIN( submitTime ) FROM quiz_answer_details WHERE quizId
    IN (SELECT id FROM quiz_details WHERE uploadtime =  '2014-04-03')
    AND answer IN (SELECT answer FROM quiz_details WHERE uploadtime =  '2014-04-03')) ";
$this->db->select('employeeCode');
$this->db->from('employee_details');
$this->db->where('employeeCode IN('.$subquery.')',null,FALSE);
$query=$this->db->get();
```

You should pass third parameter as FASLE in order to prevent the query to be quoted by bacticks 
Or you can use `query()` fucntion to run your raw queries

```
$query=$this->db->query(' your full query here');
$query->result();
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies with this code and subsequent similar uses of `where_in`

```
$this->db->where_in('employeeCode');
```

You have given the **where** parameter value but not **what to match with**.

for eg.

```
$this->db->where_in('employeeCode',$subQuery1);
```

---

The [documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html) of `where_in`:

> $this->db->where_in();
>
> Generates a WHERE field IN ('item', 'item') SQL query joined with AND
>   if appropriate
>
> $names = array('Frank', 'Todd', 'James');
>   $this->db->where_in('username', $names); // Produces: WHERE username
>   IN ('Frank', 'Todd', 'James')

---

You have to create a separate sub query for each invocation of `where_in`.