# CodeIgniter Active Record: Debugging without running SQL

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

I'm fairly new to Code Igniter, and I'm using Active Record for all the queries in a new project.

Is there a way to output the SQL statement without actually running it.

The function i've created has quite a few statements in it, selects, deletes and updates, and I want to make sure they are correct before running them in a test environment as they have a lot of Ifs and cases around them to build up the queries.

So in short, I just want it to echo the statement, but not run it.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Assuming you put the query into a variable, just: echo $myquery;

Comment: read here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113675/codeigniter-active-record-generate-but-do-not-execute-query

Comment: so if i use 'echo $this->db->last_query();' it will display the query but it wont run it?

Comment: Surely if the $this->db->updat('table' $data) has been already sent, it will run?

Comment: As an additional note: enabling the profiler will greatly help you debug your MySQL queries, configuration options, post, get and session data with every page. It can be enabled by adding `$this->output->enable_profiler(true);` in your Controller's `__construct` function.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the `insert_string()` and `update_string()` methods listed in the [Database Query Helper](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/helpers.html) section of the user guide.

For select you'll need to run $this->db->last_query() after you've run the command, but SELECT is non-destructive so who cares.

Comment: exactly, the select statements i'm fine with, its the update and delete queries i'm wary of, I want to be able to display them without running.  will look at the help section. thanks

Comment: The insert/update string is handy to output, but it doesnt work with a query built up in active record.

Comment: It certainly should do. How are you using it?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this answer of mine.
[How can I rewrite this SQL into CodeIgniter's Active Records?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10502778/how-can-i-rewrite-this-sql-into-codeigniters-active-records/10546395#10546395)

In this if you use $this->db->_compile_select() and then echo  it it will display the query without running.